# Android viewmodel transformations map not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have a view with button -

My view code -

```
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModel()

    override fun onCreateView(...): View? {
        //Button click
        view.getMyData.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.onGetDataClicked.observe(this, Observer {
            view?.progressBar?.isVisible = it.loading
            view?.description?.text = it.data.value
        })
        }
        return view
    }
```

My view model code -

```
val viewState = MyViewState()

    val onGetDataClicked =
        Transformations.map(myDomain.getData(MyAction.GetMyDataAction)) {
            when (it) {
                is MyResult.Loading -> viewState.copy(loading = true, error = null)
                is MyResult.Success -> viewState.copy(
                    loading = false,
                    data = it.data,
                    error = null
                )
                is MyResult.Error -> viewState.copy(
                    loading = false,
                    error = it.error
                )
                else -> viewState.copy(loading = false)
            }
        }
```

Here is the code for MyViewState() -

```
data class MyViewState(
    val loading: Boolean = false,
    val data: MyModel = MyModel(),
    val error: MyResult.ErrorType? = null
) : ViewState
```

When I open the app and click the button, the call goes to viewmodel and from there to domain and then I observe my data. But on second time button click, the viewmodel is not called at all from my view. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 7):

The thing is if you **do not register any observer** on your live data, **it will not trigger**. So you can not debug or see it at your viewModel.

Answer (score 0):

In your `view.getMyData.setOnClickListener` you just observe the `viewModel.onGetDataClicked` and did not trigger a new call to `myDomain.getData`. You need a way to trigger your domain function per user click.

```
override fun onCreateView(...): View? {

     onGetDataClicked.observe(this, Observer {
        view?.progressBar?.isVisible = it.loading
        view?.description?.text = it.data.value
     })

    view.getMyData.setOnClickListener {
       getDataFromDomain()
    }

    return view
}

val onGetDataClicked = MediatorLiveData<MyViewState>()

fun getDataFromDomain(){
    onGetDataClicked.addSource(myDomain.getData(MyAction.GetMyDataAction)){
        when (it) {
            is MyResult.Loading -> viewState.copy(loading = true, error = null)
            is MyResult.Success -> viewState.copy(
                loading = false,
                data = it.data,
                error = null
            )
            is MyResult.Error -> viewState.copy(
                loading = false,
                error = it.error
            )
            else -> viewState.copy(loading = false)
        }
    }
    )
}
```

---

**UPDATE**
Another solution is to use `Transformation.switchMap`. In this solution we will create a `LiveData` to convert click events to an observable (name it `clickLiveData`).
And in the `onCreateView` set a click listener to update `clickLiveData`.
Another LiveData can observe the `clickLiveData` and do a switchMap:

```
val clickLiveData = MutableLiveData<Any>()

val dataFromDomainLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(clickLiveData){
    Transformations.map(myDomain.getData(MyAction.GetMyDataAction)) {
        when (it) {
            is MyResult.Loading -> viewState.copy(loading = true, error = null)
            is MyResult.Success -> viewState.copy(
                loading = false,
                data = it.data,
                error = null
            )
            is MyResult.Error -> viewState.copy(
                loading = false,
                error = it.error
            )
            else -> viewState.copy(loading = false)
        }
    }
}



override fun onCreateView(...): View? {

    view.getMyData.setOnClickListener {
       clickLiveData.value = Any()
    }

    viewModel.dataFromDomainLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
        view?.progressBar?.isVisible = it.loading
        view?.description?.text = it.data.value
    })        


    return view
}
```

Comment: But it is using MediatorLiveData...I wanted using Transformations.map. Moreover it works on first click. When I do second click it doesnt work.

Comment: Im pretty sure it should work with multiple clicks. Did you test it?